# Rewrite url in nginx config

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-location

I want to rewrite url

https://www.beecow.info/product/whosaler-san-pham-shop-dang-590-34-390-k-p345954

to 
https://www.beecow.info/whosaler-san-pham-shop-dang-590-34-390-k-p345954

I want to remove apart /product/ And here is my nginx config

```
server {
listen      80;
server_name beecow.info;
return 301 https://www.beecow.info$request_uri;
}

server {
listen       80 default_server;
listen       [::]:80 default_server;
server_name  www.beecow.info localhost;
root         /var/www/html/;

# Load configuration files for the default server block.
#include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
   rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$server_name$1 permanent;
}

location ~* ^/product/(.*){
        rewrite ^/product/(.*)$ /$1 last;    
}

location / {
        try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;
}
```

But It can't work.The url not change anymore.

Comment: Please give me some advices.i very appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Your rewrite doesn't change it:

```
location ~* ^/product/(.*){
    rewrite ^/product/(.*)$ /$1 last;    
}
```

Something like this will do the job (untested):

```
location ~ /product/(.*)$ {
     rewrite ^ /$1?$args permanent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Aykut.I tried like your comment but nothing happen.

location / {
 try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;
}

location ~ /product/(.*)$ {
     rewrite ^ /$1?$args permanent;
}